# Как передать значения выбранных checkbox через meta_query WP

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

Я пытаюсь вывести посты в WP через meta_query. Нужно отфильтровать записи по выбранным чекбоксам.

```
<?php if($_GET['price'] && !empty($_GET['price'])) { // получаю значения выбранных чекбоксов
    foreach($_GET['price'] as $price) {
            echo $price;
        }
    } ?>

<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" id="100" value="100" name="price[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="200" value="200" name="price[]">
<input type="checkbox" id="300" value="300" name="price[]">
</form>

$args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'products',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                                'key' => 'product_price',
                                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                                'value' => $price,
                                'compare' => 'IN'
                            )
                        )
                    );
$products = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Если выбираю отмечаю сразу несколько чекбоксов, echo выводит все выбранные значения, но на странице выводятся записи только по последнему выбранному чекбоксу. Как сделать, чтобы выводились посты по нескольким значениям одновременно, а не по одному?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

value должно быть массивом.

```
$prices = $_GET['price'];

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'product_price',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'value'   => $prices,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);

$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Если писать if($_GET['price'] && !empty($_GET['price'])) {$price = $_GET['price'];} то выводятся посты также по одному последнему выбранному значению

Comment: Какое отношение это имеет к вопросу и моему ответу? Что выводит `var_dump($prices)` после первой строчки моего кода?

Comment: И вставьте в вопрос весь код, включая вызов `WP_Query`.

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "100" [1]=> string(2) "200" }

Comment: Вы вставляете в своём коде скалярную переменную $price,  анадо массив $prices. Скопируйте мой код как есть, и выкиньте свой цикл.

Comment: Дополнил ответ полным кодом

Comment: Пишу if($_GET['price'] && !empty($_GET['price'])) {
         $price = $_GET['price'];
     var_dump($price);
     } Возвращает то же самое - array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "200" [1]=> string(2) "300" }

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Ваш код сработал!